# How to enable minify in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt 3 and the result of `npm run generate` it not minified code.

I find many solutions for Nuxt 2 using `build.html.minify` in `nuxt.config.ts`, but this does not seem to exist in Nuxt 3.

```
TS2322: Type '{ html: { minify: {}; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ transpile?: (string | Function | { exec?: ((string: string) =&gt; RegExpExecArray | null) | undefined; test?: ((string: string) =&gt; boolean) | undefined; ... 14 more ...; [Symbol.matchAll]?: ((str: string) =&gt; IterableIterator&lt;...&gt;) | undefined; } | undefined)[] | undefined; templates?: any[] | undefined; analyze?: any...'.<br/>Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'html' does not exist in type '{ transpile?: (string | Function | { exec?: ((string: string) =&gt; RegExpExecArray | null) | undefined; test?: ((string: string) =&gt; boolean) | undefined; ... 14 more ...; [Symbol.matchAll]?: ((str: string) =&gt; IterableIterator&lt;...&gt;) | undefined; } | undefined)[] | undefined; templates?: any[] | undefined; analyze?: any...'.
```

Comment: It does not minify by default?

Comment: Well, it contains linebreaks and lots of `<!--[-->`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated code is already minified by default.

However it might contain a few linebreaks in html files generated by nitro in the `.output/public` folder, but we're talking about a few bytes at most. I'm actually not sure why this happens.

The generated comments such as `<!--[-->` are here for vuejs to handle conditional rendering properly in some edge cases after hydration.

They are therefore required for the app to run properly.

(See [Evan You's comment on github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5117#issuecomment-284927949) on this subject)